# In circular motion of a particle is the velocity of particle always perpendicular to the centripetal acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

- In circular motion of a particle is the velocity of particle always perpendicular to the centripetal acceleration?
- Are there any exceptions?
- Why or why not ?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie I edited the question. Does it fit the rules now ?

Comment: [There is a discussion about reopening the question here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33873501#33873501). On the basis of this I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Centripetal* acceleration is straight towards the centre.

Meanwhile, velocity is always *tangential* to the path. You can therefore see the direction of velocity by drawing the tangent to the circle.

The tangient to a circle will *at all points* be perpendicular to the direction towards the centre.

So, yes, in **circular motion** the velocity is always perpendicular - And no, no exceptions.